# How do you list all child processes in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using a third party library that starts various sub processes.  When there's an exception I'd like to kill all the child processes.  How can I get a list of child pids?

Comment: Might help to tell us your OS, since this is going to be platform dependent

Comment: Does POSIX help you? I assume some people would like to know the Windows answer too.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4229404/376587

Answer (score 54):

You can't always log all the sub-processes as they are created, since they can in turn create new processes that you are not aware of. However, it's pretty simple to use [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to find them:

```py
import psutil

current_process = psutil.Process()
children = current_process.children(recursive=True)
for child in children:
    print('Child pid is {}'.format(child.pid))
```

Answer (score 4):

It's usually safer to log the pids of all your child processes when you create them. There isn't a posix compliant way to list child PIDs. I know this can be done with the PS tool.

Comment: Yeah, I expected that. The problem is it's not me creating the processes, it's the third party library. Oh well. It's not a showstopper.

Comment: Actually your answer is not the solution. I really needs to know how I can get ``psutil.Process`` to give me recursive ``memory_info`` and ``cpu_percent`` but my call to subprocess actually open other subprocess (at least 4 or 5 levels) an I have no way to keep a track of all the PIDs.

Comment: This give us a little more informations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332043/obtaining-pid-of-child-process

Comment: Natim, your problem has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the recommended method. If, however, you don't want to depend on an external library, you can use the `--ppid` of the `ps` command to filter processes by parent id. (Assuming you're running on an OS with `ps`, of course.)

Here's a snippet that shows how to call it:

```
ps_output = run(['ps', '-opid', '--no-headers', '--ppid', str(os.getpid())],
                stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf8')
child_process_ids = [int(line) for line in ps_output.stdout.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using psutil you can get all children process (even recursive process) look at https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.children