# obtaining pid of child process

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing

I am using python's multiprocessing module to spawn new process

as follows :

```
import multiprocessing
import os
d = multiprocessing.Process(target=os.system,args=('iostat 2 > a.txt',))
d.start()
```

I want to obtain pid of iostat command or the command executed using multiprocessing
  module

When I execute :

```
 d.pid
```

it gives me pid of subshell in which this command is running .

Any help will be valuable .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 45):

Similar to @rakslice, you can use **psutil**:

```
import signal, psutil
def kill_child_processes(parent_pid, sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    try:
      parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
      return
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for process in children:
      process.send_signal(sig)
```

Comment: Why do `os.kill(pid.pid, sig)` instead of `pid.send_signal(sig)`? As in, why not use the API psutil gives you already? Also, `pid.send_signal` is supposedly safer as it should avoid race conditions such as when the original process with the given PID finishes and another one uses the same PID.

Comment: Agree. pid.send_signal(sig) seems safer. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Since you appear to be using Unix, you can use a quick `ps` command to get the details of the child processes, like I did here (this is Linux-specific):

```
import subprocess, os, signal

def kill_child_processes(parent_pid, sig=signal.SIGTERM):
        ps_command = subprocess.Popen("ps -o pid --ppid %d --noheaders" % parent_pid, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        ps_output = ps_command.stdout.read()
        retcode = ps_command.wait()
        assert retcode == 0, "ps command returned %d" % retcode
        for pid_str in ps_output.split("\n")[:-1]:
                os.kill(int(pid_str), sig)
```

Comment: On a Mac: `ps -o pid,ppid -ax | grep <PPID> | cut -f 1 -d " " | tail -1`

Comment: Gah, yeah, my answer's probably Linux-specific.

Comment: To get all children recursively, you can instead use:
`subprocess.Popen('pstree -p %d | perl -ne \'print "$1 " while /\((\d+)\)/g\'' % parent_pid, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 2):

For your example you may use the `subprocess` package. By default it executes the command without shell (like `os.system()`) and provides a PID:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen('iostat 2 > a.txt', shell=True)
processId = p.pid
p.communicate() # to wait until the end
```

The `Popen` also provides ability to connect to standard input and output of the process.

note: before using `shell=True` be aware of the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

Comment: If you want to use subprocess.Popen without the shell option, you can't give it a shell command (like the single string with multiple parameters and a redirection shown here).

Comment: This is incorrect. The process pid is bash. The child process will be something else, usually pid+1, but can be found with something like `pgrep -P parent_pid`. Nevermind your example would get stuck :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think with the multiprocess module you might be out of luck since you are really forking python directly and are given that Process object instead of the process you are interested in at the bottom of the process tree.

An alternative way, but perhaps not optimal way, to get that pid is to use the [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) module to look it up using the pid obtained from your Process object.  Psutil, however, is system dependent and will need to be installed separately on each of your target platforms.

Note:  I'm not currently at a machine I typically work from, so I can't provide working code nor play around to find a better option, but will edit this answer when I can to show how you might be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
[me@localhost ~]$ echo $$
30399
[me@localhost ~]$ cat iostat.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4 

import multiprocessing
import os
d = multiprocessing.Process(target=os.system,args=('iostat 2 > a.txt',))
d.start()

[me@localhost ~]$ ./iostat.py &
[1] 31068
[me@localhost ~]$ watch -n 3 'pstree -p 30399'
[me@localhost ~]$
```

This gave me the PID of `iostat` See image. [image: process tree]