# How to get the pid of a started Manager in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Manager in python multiprocessing, Since a manager started , a subprocess is spawned, How can I get the pid of the subprocess? THX

Comment: Show us your (minimal) code.

Comment: There are a few suggestions on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332043/obtaining-pid-of-child-process) thread.

Answer (score 1):

Too late an answer for user1221244, but something that could help future readers of this thread:

As of PY361, the PID of the Manager() instance could possibly be obtained as demoed in the code below:

```
import multiprocessing;
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mngr = multiprocessing.Manager();
    print('Manager process Pid:', Mngr._process.ident);
```

Note though that because the above involves access to a object marked as private (_process), it might change in future releases.