# Kill subprocess.call after KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, process, subprocess, kill

I need to stop a process created using `subprocess.call` in Python when I get a Keyboard Interrupt (ctrl-c)

The issue is p doesn't get a value assigned to it till it finishes execution

> p = subprocess.call(cmd)

So I cant use `os.kill` to kill that. Also, can't use `shell=True` because reasons.

What I would like to do is :

```
try:
  p = subprocess.call(cmd)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGTERM)
  sys.exit('exited after ctrl-c')
```

Comment: You can get the pid of a child process as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332043/obtaining-pid-of-child-process

Comment: Thanks, but it's *nix specific. I need compat on Windows too.

Answer (score 12):

1. `p` is just an integer (`.returncode`) and therefore there is no `.pid` attribute (run *your* code, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and see what happens)
2. On POSIX, `SIGINT` is sent to the foreground process group of the terminal and therefore the child should be killed without any additional actions on your part, see [How <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/1321)
   You can check whether the child is terminated on Windows too.

If the child were not killed on `KeyboardInterrupt` then you could do it manually: [`subprocess.call()` is just `Popen().wait()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b01cfb8f69e0990be0615b8613a7412f88bd217a/Lib/subprocess.py#L552-L566) -- you could call it yourself:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
try:
    p.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    try:
       p.terminate()
    except OSError:
       pass
    p.wait()
```