# get list of name of processes in task manger

Tags: python, c++, taskmanager

So basically how can I get the name of the processes in the task manager using c++ or python ( I mean the name of the application in processes  not in detail like a picture)
[image]

most of the code that I found when I searched shows names in detail, not in processes

Comment: if I understand your question, do you need only the name of the running software and you don't care about the actual process?

Comment: to be clear for you @shaigindin  i want the name of running software with children processes for example I want four output (or names) for alteryx designer program as show in pic

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tasklist /APPS` command to know all processes and then filter one you need.

```py
import os
print([i.split("\n") for i in os.popen("tasklist /APPS /FO \"LIST\"").read().split("\n\n")])
```

example output:

```
[['Image Name:   Cortana.exe (App)', 'PID:          17576', 'Mem Usage:    61,176 K', 'Package Name: Microsoft.549981C3F5F10_4.2203.4603.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe'], ...]
```

Comment: this does not work see my comment up for more explanation

Comment: @zkz if you need children processes just remove `/APPS`

Comment: also if remove /APPS it shows names of processes in detail windows not in processes windows for task manger

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on python here are some example codes
before copying, install first the wmi using

> py -m pip install wmi

```
import wmi

# Initializing the wmi constructor
f = wmi.WMI()

# Printing the header for the later columns
print("pid Process name")

# Iterating through all the running processes
for process in f.Win32_Process():
    
    # Displaying the P_ID and P_Name of the process
    print(f"{process.ProcessId:<10} {process.Name}")
```

for more detail, you can look here [Python Get List running processes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-list-of-running-processes/)

Comment: this shows names of processes in detail windows  not in processes windows

Comment: Oh yeah sure here are some discussion about subprocesses hope it help [Subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162096/how-do-you-list-all-child-processes-in-python)

Comment: I saw this but unfortunately is not what I want