# Why does Popen.terminate() terminate subprocess run with command interpreter (cmd.exe) on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess, kill-process

Killing subprocess created with `shell=True` passed to `subprocess.Popen`'s constructor under Linux kills only shell and not the process created by shell (see [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/)). However `python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-t', 'google.com'], shell=True).terminate()"` run under Windows Vista x64 SP3 and Python 2.7.3 64bit kills the `ping` process. Under Windows `subprocess.Popen.terminate()` [calls](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Lib/subprocess.py#l1019) `TerminateProcess`. However [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714.aspx) of this function states

> Terminates the specified process and all of its threads.

There is no mention about terminating whole process tree. What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting, this contradicts <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230669/subprocess-deleting-child-processes-in-windows>

Comment: @cdarke Interesting, indeed. Thanks for linking to that question. I asked about versions or Python and Windows in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is only with the one-liner you give, and my observations suggest that the `ping` does not even get started.  If you run as a script (Windows 7):

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-t', 'google.com'], shell=True)

raw_input("<RETURN> to terminate")
proc.terminate()

raw_input("<RETURN> to end")
```

Then the `proc.terminate()` only terminates the shell, it does *not* terminate the `ping`!

However, if you set `shell=False` then it behaves as expected - it terminates the `ping`.  Same behaviour on Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Edit:  I tried this code as a one-liner as well, and got the same results as the questioner.  I hate `sleep` hacks, but this works:

```
python -c "import subprocess,time;proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-t', 'google.com'], shell=True);time.sleep(1);proc.terminate()"
```

Comment: Nice work. I get the same results on Windows XP SP3. Any idea why `sleep()` changes behavior?

Comment: I can only guess.  I suspect that the terminate kills the shell before it gets chance to launch `ping`.  I looked at the 2.7 source code (Python-2.7.2/PC/_subprocess.c, function sp_TerminateProcess) and it did nothing unusual, it just calls `TerminateProcess`, as the doc says.