# Auto kill process and child process of multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, process, timeout, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing module for parallel processing.
Bellow code snippet search the string filename in X location and return the file name where the string found.
But in some cases it take long time to search process so i was trying to kill the search process with take more than 300 seconds.For that i used timeout == 300 as given bellow , this kills the search process but it dosent kill the child process spawn by bellow code.

I tried to find multiple way but no success :/

How can i kill parent process from Pool along with its child process ?

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def runCmd(cmd):
     lresult = os.popen(cmd).read()
     return lresult

main ():
     p = Pool(4)
     data_paths = [list of paths of store data]
     search_cmds = [ "SearchText.exe %s < %s"%(data_path, filename) for data_path in data_paths ]
     results = [p.apply_async(runCmd, (cmd,), callback = log_result) for cmd in search_cmds]
     try:
        for result in results:
            root.append(result.get(timeout=300))
        #rool holds the result of search process
     except TimeoutError:
        for c in multiprocessing.active_children():
            print '----->',c.pid
            os.kill(c.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
     p.close()
     p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Process Tree in Process Explorer :

```
cmd.exe
------python.exe
----------------python.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
----------------python.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
----------------python.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
----------------python.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
```

above code snippet dosnt kill the child process

```
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
--------------------------cmd.exe
---------------------------------SearchText.exe
```

Theses child search process retain , these child process also get killed .

Please guild.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am able to solve my Issue using psutil module

Found solution on bellow post:

```
import psutil, os

def kill_proc_tree(pid, including_parent=True):    
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    for child in parent.get_children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    if including_parent:
        parent.kill()

me = os.getpid()
kill_proc_tree(me)
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229404/420557

Comment: get_children doesn't exist anymore, the method is called [children](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.children)

Comment: I used daemonize, so this approach was exactly what i was looking for.