# Python multiprocessing: abort map on first child error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

What's the proper way of aborting multiprocessing when one of the child aborts and/or throw an Exception?

I found various questions around that ([generic multiprocessing error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent), [how to close multiprocessing pool on exception but without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587669/python-multiprocessing-how-to-close-the-multiprocessing-pool-on-exception/44589892#44589892), ...), but no clear answer on how to stop multiprocessing on child exception.

For instance, I expect the following code:

```
def f(x):
    sleep(x)
    print(f"f({x})")
    return 1.0 / (x - 2)


def main():
    with Pool(4) as p:
        try:
            r = p.map(f, range(7))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"oops: {e}")
            p.close()
            p.terminate()
    print("end")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To output:

```
f(0)
f(1)
f(2)
oops: float division by zero
end
```

Instead, it applies `f` function on all items before detecting/handling the exception:

```
f(0)
f(1)
f(2)
f(4)
f(3)
f(5)
f(6)
oops: float division by zero
end
```

Isn't there any way to catch the exception directly?

Comment: Note that the exception is only re-raised in the main process *after* ``map`` has finished. If you definitely want to use ``map`` there is no way to catch it any earlier, because the exception does not *exist* any earlier. So, the question is whether you want to stick to ``map`` or are looking for a custom solution?

Comment: Which python version? My **Python:3.4.2** behave as you expected.

Comment: @stovfl I've edited my post, I'm using **Python 3.6.5**

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm looking for the simplest multiprocessing with error handling - I'd like to avoid adding wrapper class or equivalent to handle it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to need `apply_async` for this, so you can act upon every single result instead of the cumulative result. `pool.apply_async` offers an `error_callback` parameter you can use to register your error-handler. `apply_async` is not blocking, so you'll need to `join()` the pool. I'm also using a flag `terminated` to know when results can be processed normally in case no exception occured.

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    sleep(x)
    print(f"f({x})")
    return 1.0 / (x - 2)

def on_error(e):
    global terminated
    terminated = True
    pool.terminate()
    print(f"oops:{e}")


def main():
    global pool
    global terminated

    terminated = False

    pool = Pool(4)
    results = [pool.apply_async(f, (x,), error_callback=on_error)
               for x in range(7)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    if not terminated:
        for r in results:
            print(r.get())

    print("end")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```