# difference between os._exit() and os._exit(1) when multiprocessing

Tags: python

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for number in test_list:
    pool.apply_async(func=test_quit, args=[number, ])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

when i call os._exit(), the program terminate successfully

```
def test_quit(number):
    if number == 1:
        print("1 should exit")
        os._exit()
```

but when i use os._exit(1), the program is still working.

```
def test_quit(number):
    if number == 1:
        print("1 should exit")
        os._exit(1)
```

so whats the difference of this two func, why os._exit(1) can not stop the program

Comment: Which operating system? On UNIXy platforms, `os._exit()` is _not_ a successful exit (but as an `os._anything()` function, its behavior is allowed to be locally different).

Comment: @Legit007, `os.exit(0)` would behave the same as `os.exit(1)` for the OP's purpose here; it's only `os.exit()`, with the argument missing that's different.

Answer (score 1):

`os._exit()` throws a `TypeError` because it's not a valid use (`_exit`'s argument is mandatory), and thereby engages `multiprocessing`'s error-handling machinery.

`os._exit(1)` stops *the specific process you're in*, but because you're using `multiprocessing`, your program consists of multiple processes, so stopping the one process does not stop the whole program. (This is one of the ways in which multiprocessing is different from multithreading in practice).

Comment: so if i want to end the main processing when some error happen in sub processing, which func should i use.

Comment: None of the above. `os._exit()` in a multiprocessing-created process risks corrupting the communication channels out of your processes back to the main one. If "how do I abort on the first error in `multiprocessing`?" is the question you really meant to ask, I'd argue that it's already asked and answered as [Python multiprocessing: abort map on first child error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272325/python-multiprocessing-abort-map-on-first-child-error).

Comment: (note that the above question's answer instructs the OP to use `apply_async()`, as you're already doing).