# How to kill subprocess python in windows

Tags: python

How would I go about killing a process on Windows?

I am starting the process with

```
    self.p = Process(target=self.GameInitialize, args=(testProcess,))
    self.p.start()
```

I have tried

```
self.p.kill()
self.p.terminate()
os.kill(self.p.pid, -1)
os.killpg(self.p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

Errors

```
Process Object has no Attribute kill
Process Object has no Attribute terminate
Access Denied
```

I cannot use `.join.`

Comment: [os.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) should be sufficient.

Comment: what is the second argument? signal is not defined.

Comment: os.kill(self.p.pid, -1) returns access denied

Comment: possible duplicate of [subprocess: deleting child processes in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230669/subprocess-deleting-child-processes-in-windows)

Comment: I cannot use psutil, I was hoping to do this without an external library.

Comment: Please elaborate on how your attempted ways "didn't work". `terminate` calls `TerminateProcess` that kills the process immediately (provided you have rights) [even if it seems to not go away immediately](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx).

Comment: It replies: Process Object has no Attribute terminate

Comment: That can't be if it's really a `multiprocessing.Process` from the standard library and neither object nor the class were tampered with.

Comment: Btw, what is your Python version and flavor?

Comment: Okay, that means something is wrong with your `Process` object.

Comment: Btw, are those the exact error messages? Normally, they look a bit different.

Answer (score 26):

On windows, `os.killpg` will not work because it sends a signal to the process ID to terminate. This is now how you kill a process on Windows, instead you have to use the win32 API's `TerminateProcess` to kill a process.

So, you can kill a process by the following on windows:

```
import signal
os.kill(self.p.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

If the above does not work, then try `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` instead.

Comment: There is no `os.killpg` in Windows, and the `os.kill` implementation is deeply conflated and confused. It tries `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` if the 'signal' is either `CTRL_C_EVENT` (0) or `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` (1). Otherwise it opens handle to the process and calls `TerminateProcess(handle, signal)`.

Comment: The confused part is that `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` targets a console process *group*. For a group target, POSIX `kill` requires a negative ID value, so this is wrong from the outset. Also, Windows provides no way to query a console process group ID, so the only way this makes sense (and everything else is extremely buggy) is to use group 0 (all console client processes) or to create the process as a new group with the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, for which the PGID is the PID. With this flag, Ctrl+C is initially disabled in the process, so only `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` is reliable.

Comment: If the process either has no console or isn't attached to the same console as the calling process, then `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` fails. In this case, `os.kill` continues on to try `TerminateProcess`, but in CPython this is buggy (inexcusably, but no one has patched it) because the previous exception hasn't been cleared, which leads to a `RuntimeError`. If you know a process doesn't share the same console as your process, do not even try sending `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`. It's not worth the headache. Just use `os.kill(pid, status)`, where `status > 1`.

Comment: I'm using multithreading and a queue in my calling program and it sometimes receives the KeyboardInterrupt instead of the child process -- what the hell??

Answer (score 17):

I had to do it using this method [from this link](http://mackeblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/killing-subprocesses-on-windows-in.html):

```
subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID',  str(self._active_process.pid)])
```

This is because `self._active_process.kill()` was not adequate

Comment: Fantastic, the subprocess does stop, my output on windows was: SUCCESS: The process with PID 9028 (child process of PID 25224) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 25224 (child process of PID 10340) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 10340 (child process of PID 18632) has been terminated. 

Thank you ! splendid work

Answer (score 3):

You should provide a minimal, working example of the problem you are having.  As show below, this minimal, working example correctly terminates the process (Tested on Python 2.7.5 64-bit), so the error you are seeing lies in code you haven't shown.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def work():
    while True:
        print('work process')
        time.sleep(.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Process(target=work)
    p.start()
    for i in range(3):
        print('main process')
        time.sleep(1)
    p.terminate()
    for i in range(3):
        print('main process')
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Output:

```
main process
work process
work process
main process
work process
work process
main process
work process
work process
main process
main process
main process
```

Comment: This is good indeed, but it seems, Python's multiprocessing.Process isnt very class friendly! Did you try this in a class?

Comment: @Rika Yes, converting `work` to a class derived from `Process` and with the work in a `def run(self):` works the same way.  `p = Worker()` then gives the same result.  If you have a problem post a question with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, the issue is not the worker itself, is the other class that will use worker to run the subprocess. at the very least, worker would accept an instance of the class in question, and simply execute the method which needs to be run as a seaprate thread.

```class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):    
    def __init__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):    
         super.__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
         self.obj = obj    
    def run(self):    
        self.obj.cpu_intensive_method()```
but using this inside the main class will produce pickle error. ami I missing sth here?

Answer (score 0):

```
os.kill(self.p.pid, -9)
```

Works. I am unsure why -1 returns a access denied error but -9 does not.