# in windows+python, how to kill a process with subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a python script ["MAIN" script] that uses this line:

```
# Part 4, create the process and run
cmds = list()
cmds += ['python']
cmds += [script_b]
start = time.time()
p = subprocess.Popen(cmds, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell=True)
```

This process,script_b start another, a third one, script_c. 
When i try p.kill() or p.terminate() it does not terminate script_c.
How can i terminate script_b and all its related process from the main script? 
Thx

Note:
I use it on windows 10. This script runs both on python2.7 and 3.7 if it makes any difference.

Thx

Comment: This link will help you [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551180/how-to-kill-subprocess-python-in-windows)

Comment: Use a Windows job object that disallows breakaway and is flagged to kill on close (of the handle). Keep the handle open to call `TerminateJobObject`. If your process crashes, this will be done automatically, so no child process will leak.