# How to terminate a process with python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, subprocess, terminate

I need to close an .exe at the end of my code. I was able to start the .exe file

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('.nameProgram.exe')
```

Now I have to close it but the `terminate()` function doesn't seem to work.
I tried this code:

```
proc.terminate()
```

I noticed that the exe executable is under another java process. How can I close it. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu - Exe - Python - Java !! I can't connect all these! ?

Comment: Try proc.kill()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the pid of the process started by subprocess.run and kill it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066599/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-process-started-by-subprocess-run-and-kill-it)

Comment: Additionally, you need to wait after `terminate` >> `proc.wait()`

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
ps
```

In terminal & check on which name program is runing once you run. copy that name.

```
#inside python program
import os
os.system('pkill programName')
```