# Run process with realtime output to a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to create a GUI in Tkinter python. I want to display the output of a tool to my Tkinter interface. The tool works great in command line but it is a continuous scanner. Somewhat like a continuous ping (I mean by ping command in Linux with no options).

Now the problem is since the output of ping is never complete, therefore I cannot print the output in Tkinter. It also makes my application go freeze. I also cannot stop the command after few seconds to display output. 
[Run process with realtime output in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281140/run-process-with-realtime-output-in-php)
I found this above link helpful for php, but How can I convert this code in python:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6144213/4931414

Here is some sample code that I want to display on tkinter frame

```
#!/usr....

import subprocess
x = subprocess.call(["ping", "127.0.0.1"])
print x
```

This works great on command line but I am not getting output on tkinter interface.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I must admit that I am not so familiar with the module [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) and [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html), but I have tried to create a simple console that accepts you to write a command, whose output will be shown in a [`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) widget.

The basic idea is to have a new running parallel *thread* that processes a command when you click the button `Execute`. We keep iterating through the lines of `stdout` and inserting them into the Text widget.

It seems to work for any command, but I am pretty sure that there are some problems and mistakes. If you guys more familiar with the modules I cited above see any serious problem with my code, or have any suggestions to improve it, I would definitely listen to you in order to improve this example.

Now, this is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


class Console(tk.Frame):

    """Simple console that can execute bash commands"""

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text_options = {"state": "disabled",
                             "bg": "black",
                             "fg": "#08c614",
                             "insertbackground": "#08c614",
                             "selectbackground": "#f01c1c"}

        self.text = ScrolledText(self, **self.text_options)

        # It seems not to work when Text is disabled...
        # self.text.bind("<<Modified>>", lambda: self.text.frame.see(tk.END))

        self.text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        # bash command, for example 'ping localhost' or 'pwd'
        # that will be executed when "Execute" is pressed
        self.command = ""  
        self.popen = None     # will hold a reference to a Popen object
        self.running = False  # True if the process is running

        self.bottom = tk.Frame(self)

        self.prompt = tk.Label(self.bottom, text="Enter the command: ")
        self.prompt.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.bottom)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.start_thread)
        self.entry.bind("<Command-a>", lambda e: self.entry.select_range(0, "end"))
        self.entry.bind("<Command-c>", self.clear)
        self.entry.focus()
        self.entry.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

        self.executer = tk.Button(self.bottom, text="Execute", command=self.start_thread)
        self.executer.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)
        self.clearer = tk.Button(self.bottom, text="Clear", command=self.clear)
        self.clearer.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)
        self.stopper = tk.Button(self.bottom, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stopper.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=2)

        self.bottom.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

    def clear_text(self):
        """Clears the Text widget"""
        self.text.config(state="normal")
        self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
        self.text.config(state="disabled")

    def clear_entry(self):
        """Clears the Entry command widget"""
        self.entry.delete(0, "end")

    def clear(self, event=None):
        """Does not stop an eventual running process,
        but just clears the Text and Entry widgets."""
        self.clear_entry()
        self.clear_text()

    def show(self, message):
        """Inserts message into the Text wiget"""
        self.text.config(state="normal")
        self.text.insert("end", message)
        self.text.see("end")
        self.text.config(state="disabled")

    def start_thread(self, event=None):
        """Starts a new thread and calls process"""
        self.stop()
        self.running = True
        self.command = self.entry.get()
        # self.process is called by the Thread's run method
        threading.Thread(target=self.process).start()

    def process(self):
        """Runs in an infinite loop until self.running is False""" 
        while self.running:
            self.execute()

    def stop(self):
        """Stops an eventual running process"""
        if self.popen:
            try:
                self.popen.kill()
            except ProcessLookupError:
                pass 
        self.running = False

    def execute(self):
        """Keeps inserting line by line into self.text
        the output of the execution of self.command"""
        try:
            # self.popen is a Popen object
            self.popen = Popen(self.command.split(), stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
            lines_iterator = iter(self.popen.stdout.readline, b"")

            # poll() return None if the process has not terminated
            # otherwise poll() returns the process's exit code
            while self.popen.poll() is None:
                for line in lines_iterator:
                    self.show(line.decode("utf-8"))
            self.show("Process " + self.command  + " terminated.\n\n")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.show("Unknown command: " + self.command + "\n\n")                               
        except IndexError:
            self.show("No command entered\n\n")

        self.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Console")
    Console(root).pack(expand=True, fill="both")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: just an addendum.  You want to keep a reference to psutil as when using shell=True for example, there are at least 2 and possibly 3 processes that you want to kill. Example code (works on all OS's AFAIK) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230669/subprocess-deleting-child-processes-in-windows

Comment: Excuse my clumsy explanation.  I just wanted you to know that it existed.  If you are ever in a situation where you want you close the parent and child processes, it saves a lot of time looking for a solution, and headaches.

Comment: You shouldn't call tkinter methods from a different thread. That may cause tkinter to crash.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on @nbro's answer:

```py
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread, Lock
import tkinter as tk


class Console(ScrolledText):
    """
    Simple console that can execute commands
    """

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        # The default options:
        text_options = {"state": "disabled",
                        "bg": "black",
                        "fg": "#08c614",
                        "selectbackground": "orange"}
        # Take in to account the caller's specified options:
        text_options.update(kwargs)
        super().__init__(master, **text_options)

        self.proc = None # The process
        self.text_to_show = "" # The new text that we need to display on the screen
        self.text_to_show_lock = Lock() # A lock to make sure that it's thread safe

        self.show_text_loop()

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """
        Clears the Text widget
        """
        super().config(state="normal")
        super().delete("0.0", "end")
        super().config(state="disabled")

    def show_text_loop(self) -> None:
        """
        Inserts the new text into the `ScrolledText` wiget
        """
        new_text = ""
        # Get the new text that needs to be displayed
        with self.text_to_show_lock:
            new_text = self.text_to_show.replace("\r", "")
            self.text_to_show = ""

        if len(new_text) > 0:
            # Display the new text:
            super().config(state="normal")
            super().insert("end", new_text)
            super().see("end")
            super().config(state="disabled")

        # After 100ms call `show_text_loop` again
        super().after(100, self.show_text_loop)

    def run(self, command:str) -> None:
        """
        Runs the command specified
        """
        self.stop()
        thread = Thread(target=self._run, daemon=True, args=(command, ))
        thread.start()

    def _run(self, command:str) -> None:
        """
        Runs the command using subprocess and appends the output
        to `self.text_to_show`
        """
        self.proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

        try:
            while self.proc.poll() is None:
                text = self.proc.stdout.read(1).decode()
                with self.text_to_show_lock:
                    self.text_to_show += text

            self.proc = None
        except AttributeError:
            # The process ended prematurely
            pass

    def stop(self, event:tk.Event=None) -> None:
        """
        Stops the process.
        """
        try:
            self.proc.kill()
            self.proc = None
        except AttributeError:
            # No process was running
            pass

    def destroy(self) -> None:
        # Stop the process if the text widget is to be destroyed:
        self.stop()
        super().destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def run_command_in_entry(event:tk.Event=None):
        console.run(entry.get())
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        return "break"

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Console")

    console = Console(root)
    console.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    entry = tk.Entry(root, bg="black", fg="white",
                     insertbackground="white")
    entry.insert("end", "ping 8.8.8.8 -n 4")
    entry.bind("<Return>", run_command_in_entry)
    entry.pack(fill="x")

    root.mainloop()
```

The only difference between our answers is that I removed all of the widgets that were in the class except the `ScrolledText` and I made sure that I used tkinter in a thread safe way. Parts of `tkinter` aren't thread safe and aren't meant to be called from different threads (can raise errors). In the worse case scenario tkinter can crash without giving an error or a traceback.

Answer (score -1):

If you change your code to the following you will see that ping, and not the "print x" is what is displaying on the console

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.call(["ping", "127.0.0.1"])
print "x is", x   ## or comment out this line
```

You would have to use pipes and flush stdout periodically to get what I think you want.  See popen at Doug Hellmann's Python Module of the Week http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess