# Running shell script through python tkinter

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, python-requests, tkinter-entry

I am making an application through python tkinter; I am not able to understand how I can run a shell script with it.

My use case is , when I press a button it will invoke a shell script and display its output in GUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run process with realtime output to a Tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410421/run-process-with-realtime-output-to-a-tkinter-gui)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the subprocess module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

An example:

```
subprocess.run(["ls"]). # run ls
output = subprocess.check_output(["ls"]) # grab the output of ls
```

Comment: It is throwing below error when trying to display the output in label --------------------

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: This will most likely not help OP because if the script runs for too long it can make the window unresponsive.

Comment: @AmanSinha Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name).

Comment: @TheLizzard  Thanks it resolve my issue.

Also the size of the frame in tkinter is not increasing my shell script output is not displayed correctly ; Is there a way to increase the size of that frame

Comment: @AmanSinha The frame should resize itself to fit the widgets inside. I think something else is going on but without seeing your code there is no way of me giving you an answer. Please ask a new stackoverflow question if you need to.

Comment: This is the code for frame
self.frame1 = Frame(masterwindow, width=500, height=250, bg="#00B388",borderwidth = 5)
        self.frame1.pack(padx=10, pady=250)