# How to open and close File Explorer from Python

Tags: python, windows

Using `subprocess` I want to open Windows File Explorer. Then wait for 1 second and close it:

```
import subprocess, time
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"D:\tmp\temp"')
time.sleep(1)
```

How to close File Explorer?

Comment: Other than the `terminate()` method?

Comment: read [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) documentation - there are all information - ie. `kill()`

Comment: How do you `terminate` or `kill` if `Popen` leaves no `pid` number?

Comment: im pretty sure the issue is that the process is killed almost instantly and it just puts a different explorer instance in the background

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yes this is what happens.  If the OP does `p = subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"D:\tmp\temp"');` `print(p.wait())`, it should return print an exit code of 1.

Comment: i think you could run some kind of `taskkill` command against a new Popen ...

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230669/subprocess-deleting-child-processes-in-windows

Comment: @Dekel, the new Explorer instance is launched by the DCOM service. It's not a child of the Explorer instance created by `Popen`.

Comment: If thats the case I don't think you can close it using the PID of the current subprocess you just opened.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works

```
import subprocess
import time
from pygetwindow import getWindowsWithTitle
from pywinauto import Application
# Open
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"D:\tmp\temp"')
time.sleep(1)
#locate window
explorer_windows = getWindowsWithTitle("This PC")
time.sleep(1)
# Close the window 
window = explorer_windows[0]
app = Application().connect(handle=window._hWnd)
app.top_window().close()
```